# Default configuration for WordPress Docker Container

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently working on a project using the **WordPress API**.

This is my **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/wordpress/:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/src
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
```

In order to use the **WordPress API**, I need to configure the WordPress container *manually* by going to `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin` and changing some settings.

Thing is, I need to make this settings changes **automatic** because everytime I remove the `volume` folder in order to reset the *WordPress content*, it also **removes the settings**.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that all settings configured via the wp-admin section are stored in the database.

If that's the case than you can do this:

1. Setup a first WordPress instance by running your docker-compose and completing the setup steps.
2. Stop the compose. At this point in the mysql volume folder you have a database structure with a configured wordpress in it.
3. Store the contents of the folder somewhere.

Now, if you want to create another WordPress instance, you can edit the docker-compose.yml file in order to adjust volume binding and make sure that the initial content of the mysql volume contains the data you got from step 3 above.

When you start the new docker-compose stack it'll start from a populated database and you should have a preconfigured WordPress instance.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right indeed, the settings are stored in the database. I've made a dump the first the `docker-compose up` ran and then use it in my *docker-compose.yml* file to provide the initial settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the file/folder that containes the settings that you are changing.

Start the container, do the changes and backup the settings file into your host machine using:

`docker cp <container-name>:<path-to-settings> .`

You then can create a custom image that replaces the default settings with the backuped settings you copied to the host.

```
FROM wordpress
COPY <settings-from-host> <settings-path-in-container>
```